# Modifying OpenCV source code

Tags: opencv

It may be a basic question but I'm having trouble where to start.

I get the following error from the OpenCV package. My question is: where is actually the file which gives the error located and after the possible modification how to rebuild the package to apply the changes?

```
/build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:323: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat
```

I use Anaconda as a python distribution but can't seem to find the OpenCV source code there.

Comment: You won't find the source code in a pre-built binary package (Anaconda etc.) You can download sources from the OpenCV site and build them yourself (including the Python wrappers). What makes you think the error is on the OpenCV's side, though?

Answer (score 1):

The error simply means that `cv::Rect()` you are using to create the sub matrix, has greater dimensions than your original `cv::Mat()`. Or your original `cv::Mat()` can be empty with `width, height == 0`. The source can be confirmed [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L525)

You are probably calling the `cv::Mat` constructor as:

```
cv::Mat subMat = originalMat(cropRect);
```

But not checking if the cropRect is in bounds of the originalMat size. To prevent this behavior you can place an `if` condition before cropping the `Mat` as:

```
originalRect = cv::Rect(0, 0, originalMat.cols, originalMat.rows);
// Check if crop rect completely overlaps the originalMat bounds.
if (originalRect & cropRect == cropRect) {
    subMat = originalMat(cropRect);
} else {
    std::cout << originalRect << " is less than " >> cropRect << std::endl;
}
```